# Why is gate fanout calculated like that for general gate?

Tags: digital-logic, cmos

In the given example I am currently struggling to understand why the fanout of each gate is equal to the ratio of the size of this gate to the previous gate.

In a simple chain of inverters, the fan out was defined as the ratio of the input capacitances of the current current inverter to the previous inverter so fanout was a measure of big a inverter relative to the previous one.

How is that concept still valid for general gates?

[image: chain of gate sizing]

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it be? Delay in CMOS comes from a non-zero impedance network pulling your non-zero capacitance gates to VDD or GND. If you increase your drive strength by increasing the width of your transistors or decrease the size of the gates you are driving, it will take less time to charge/discharge the gates and your delay will decrease. It doesn't matter if the gate is an inverter, the same intuition applies.

The only complicating factor is that, since delays are usually defined with reference to the unit inverter, you can no longer simply take the ratio of input and output capacitance to calculate the delay once the gates become more complicated. This is what is given as "g" for each gate above, which stands for gain.

Gain is defined as electrical effort * logical effort. Electrical effort is simply how many gates you are driving (which is always equal to 1 in the example above) and logical effort relates the delay performance of the gate relative to a reference inverter. See these [lecture notes](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee141_f05/Lectures/Notes/ComputingLogicalEffort.pdf) for how to calculate logical effort.

So, ratio of input and output capacitance is still extremely relevant for calculating delay in logic circuits. However you can think of the logical effort as the "correction factor" which describes the lower output drive to input capacitance ratio of gates more complicated than inverters.

Hope that helps.